# Можно ли "зафиксировать" несколько колонок в таблице?

Tags: html, css

Я изменяю ширину в `div.example`. При этом хотелось бы, что бы ширина первых 3 колонок не изменялась, а только 4-ая (сделана специально для этого) расширялась:

```html
<table border="1" style="empty-cells: show;">
  <tr>
    <td>ячейка-1</td>
    <td>cell-1</td>
    <td>data-1-2-3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div class="example" style="width: 300px;">
        div.example
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Хотелось бы получить такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Border я добавил для наглядности, они не нужны.

Можно выставить последней ячейке `width: 99%`, но тогда вся таблица расширяется. Объедененной ячейке можно выставить `overflow-x: visible` (и убрать четвертую ячейку), но это не сработает, если ширина не зафиксирована.

В конечном итоге эти рядки будут повторятся, и нужно, что бы колонки имели одинаковую ширину (по-этому я не могу сделать таблицу отдельно):

```html
<table border="1" style="empty-cells: show;">
  <tr>
    <td>ячейка-1</td>
    <td>cell-1</td>
    <td>data-1-2-3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div class="example" style="width: 300px;">
        div.example
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text</td>
    <td>long-long-text</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div class="example" style="width: 300px;">
        div.example
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Прямо указать ``<td width="75">`` (ширина в пикселях) не поможет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать сделать так:

```css
.holder {
  width: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" style="empty-cells: show;">
  <tr>
    <td class="holder">ячейка-1</td>
    <td class="holder">cell-1</td>
    <td class="holder">data-1-2-3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4">
      <div class="example" style="width: 300px;">
        div.example
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Не слушай никого, кто говорит, что нельзя верстать таблицами, если ситуация и душа требуют таблиц.

А зафиксировать ширину у колонок просто: нужно первым трем колонкам проставить фиксированный `width`, а таблице - плавающий, скажем, `width:100%`. Все, при изменении ширины таблицы будет плавать ширина последней колонки. Если что, это работает еще с прошлого века, это один из основных столпов таблиц.

Конечно, придется принять меры, чтобы первые три колонки не распирало контентом, но это дело десятое.

Answer (score 0):

Этот код, согласно валидации, не верен. Так делать нельзя! 
Лучше сверстай тоже самое, но в блочной верстке через flexbox. 
Поставь фиксированную ширину первым трем столбцам, а четвертый будет двигаться самостоятельно (исходя из контента)

Comment: Валидатор ругается лишь на border, во всём остальном код верен, а border сути вопроса не касается

Comment: Этот код валиден

Comment: Бордер добавлен для наглядности, и что бы не усложнять пример.